# Send new Jade page with Socket.io without reloading

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

so I am wanting to load a Jade page when *something* happens. So when people go to my website, which is a game, they can see the *About the Game* and *Game Details* sections (`index.jade`). Once they click 'Create Room' I want to delete the page that has all that information and load the `room.jade` page. I've seen plenty of ways on here how to do it with HTML, but see the problem I face is I want to load `room.jade` with my `template.jade` (which has the header and footer stuff). But if I put `room.jade` in my `template.jade` wouldn't that load `room.jade` when the page loads?

My question: How can I unload `index.jade` and then load `room.jade` with `template.jade` on a event (in this case, a button click) using socket.io? The only examples I've been able to find are with regular HTML pages and Ajax calls.

Comment: You would contact your server with an Ajax call and ask if for the content for room.jade.  When you get that result back from the Ajax call, you would use client-side Javascript to remove the index.jade content from the current DOM and then insert the newly retrieved content in its place.  This is using Javascript to dynamically manipulate the current page contents.

Comment: Is this not possible using just socket.io? As I'm wanting to stay away from using Ajax.

Comment: You could make the request over your socket.io connection and fetch the data that way.  FYI, there's no reason to "stay away from Ajax".